# Listing all the chars in a given UnicodeBlock

Tags: java, unicode

I want to visually inspect all the characters that Java thinks are in any given UnicodeBlock. The following method, as far as I can tell, does the task. But, it sure feels like awful design.

```
public static void displayUnicodeBlock(Character.UnicodeBlock block) {
    int maxCharVal = (int) Math.pow(2, 16);
    for(int cInt = 0; cInt <= maxCharVal; cInt++) {
        char c = (char) cInt;           
        if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == block) { 
            System.out.println("_" + c + "_");
        }
    }
}
```

- Would reflection be the ideal solution?
- Can reflection actually show every character in a UnicodeBlock? How?
- My solution is stupid because it is inefficient?
- My solution is stupid because it is hardwired with 2^16?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is truly unfortunate that `Character.UnicodeBlock` doesn't have a `min()` and `max()`.  In fact, the way it is implemented in OpenJDK is as a [private static  `blockStarts` table](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.UnicodeBlock.0blockStarts), which is entirely unhelpful to you.

I don't have a better solution, but rather a complication.  The Java `char` type only covers the Basic Multilingual Plane.  To be pedantic, you would need to cover even larger codepoints, with [`Character.UnicodeBlock.of(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#of(int))!  (For example, [`Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_B`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_B) starts at U+20000, which cannot be encoded using a single `char`, and therefore iterating up to 2<sup>16</sup> would not find it.)

It appears that [existing Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block) have sizes that are multiples of 16, so you could take advantage of that instead of testing every single codepoint.

Code blocks are contiguous.  Therefore, a possible optimization is that once you have found a character that is in the desired block, if you then encounter a character that is not in the block, then you're done.

Comment: With regard to your complication, does the range from 0 to Math.pow(2, Character.SIZE) cover every possible character that Java can represent? If not, then what does "Character.SIZE" mean? btw: the optimizations are very informative. thank you.

Comment: `Character.SIZE` is just hard-coded to 16. However, some of the rarer Unicode characters have codepoints greater than 2^16 — they are said to be outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29).

Answer (score 2):

The `maxCharVal` initializer can be replaced with `0xffff` or the static value `Character.MAX_VALUE`. This removes the hard wire and the slow pow function.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `Math.Pow` using constants? Replace it with 65,536.

Comment: "Math.Pow(2, 16)" is sort of self-documenting. Seeing "65536" is too unsettling. I've gotta focus just to see if it has 5 digits.

Comment: @dwakam however 1 << 16 is still faster and also self-documenting (though admittedly to a lesser effect), either way my suggestion of Character.MAX_VALUE eliminates both and is fully self documenting.